# Servlet to integrate data from multiple threads

Tags: java, servlets

How do we allow client collaboration in Servlets. As Servlets create a `new thread` for every client/new request from a client, Lets say I wanted to add integers provided by different authenticated clients for a servlet.

How do I allow those integers to be taken from different clients, added and results produced added to a file which is shared between those clients ?
More or less, it probably should work like a group, where members of those groups are able to see the shared file and make changes to it.

I understand it is a broad question but I find myself pretty directionless at the moment.

Comment: Put them into a shared data structure, like in application scope?

Comment: BTW, a container doesn't create a new thread for each request. It borrows a thread from a pool, and puts it back in the pool when the request is done.

Comment: You mean ServletContext ? In that case all the clients that connect to the servlet will have the access to it, right ?

Comment: @JBNizet: Right , I apologize. Had confused it with CGI.

Comment: Your question is about how threads communicate with each other and that's quite broad question with many books and articles written for it. There's nothing special about servlets in that aspect.